# Word 2011 for Mac: keyboard shortcut for turning balloons on/off in review mode

Tags: macos, ms-office

Does anybody know if I can create a keyboard shortcut to toggle "Use balloons to display changes"?

Also, is there a webpage where one can vote for features for the next Word release? I want to have the option to show only comments in balloons and not deleted text that existed in previous versions back.

Thanks

Comment: I've been requesting this feature (which has been standard in Word for Windows forever) for the better part of a decade. Good luck getting MS to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

There is not one. But you're in luck, because you can assign one using `Tools -> Customize Keyboard`. See the example below.

[image]